# Snowflake Internal and external stage

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why snowflake has internal and external stages when all the data is stored in a cloud storage service(say AWS)? What is the difference basically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Overview of Data Loading](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-overview.htm) says it really well:

> Snowflake refers to the location of data files in cloud storage as a stage. The COPY INTO  command used for both bulk and continuous data loads (i.e. Snowpipe) supports cloud storage accounts managed by your business entity (i.e. external stages) as well as cloud storage contained in your Snowflake account (i.e. internal stages).

Some of the base pages in the doc's are really very worth while reading.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that if you do not have your own Storage Account on any Cloud provider, you can still use the scalability and the power of Cloud Storage with the internal Stage.
With the internal stage, the storage cost will be billed by Snowflake to you.
If you have your own AWS account, you can use an external stage, here the storage cost is billed to you by your cloud provider.

With the external stage, you have more control over the data using Policies etc.
It really depends on the use case and how you want to use the storage.
You can check more on this 3rd party article:
https://cloudyard.in/2022/01/snowflake-internal-stage-and-external-stage/